# Curves with Constant Curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Besides lines, circles and helices, are there any other curves that have a constant curvature $\kappa$?

If there exist any, are there any that have an explicit formula in the form of r(t) = [x(t) , y(t) , z (t)] ?

Comment: At least in $2$D, circle and line are the only curves of constant curvature. But in higher dimensions you have more parameters to play with.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, of course. You've just listed those with constant curvature *and* torsion.

I like to think of curves of constant curvature in terms of the Darboux vector
$$\omega = \tau T + \kappa B$$
which gives the axis-angle of infinitesimal rotation of the curve's frame at every point. Here $\tau$ is free, so you can get different curves of constant curvature by changing how much you *twist about the tangent* as you travel along the curve.

You can find formulas for the curves $r(t)$ by solving the Frenet-Serret equations:
\begin{align*}
r'(t) &= T(t)\\
T'(t) &= \omega \times T(t)\\
N'(t) &= \omega \times N(t)\\
B'(t) &= \omega \times B(t)
\end{align*}
which is a system of first-order ODEs that can be integrated up given appropriate initial values. Whether or not $r$ has a closed form will depend on the complexity of your chosen torsion $\tau(t)$.

Comment: Just to make it crystal clear: You get a unique space curve (up to rigid motion) once you specific curvature ($\kappa>0$) and torsion. So, you'll get different curves whenever you specify different torsion functions.